# Why my selecting data only show the last data?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

why i cannot select the first data and the second data when i tested using console.log

This is the table:
[image: this is the table]

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("recommendations");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    // console.log(snapshot.val());
    var recommendations = snapshot.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(recommendations);
    console.log(keys);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var title = recommendations[k].title;
    var link = recommendations[k].link;
    var presenter = recommendations[k].presenter;

    // document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
    // document.getElementById('presenter').innerHTML = presenter;
    // document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = link;
    var table = document.getElementById("data");

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    var td2= tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    var td3 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    var tdEdit = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

    td1.innerHTML = title;
    td2.innerHTML = presenter;
    td3.innerHTML = link;
    tdEdit.innerHTML = "<button id='"+k+"' class='btn btn-default edit'>Edit</button>";
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit").on("click", function(){
        console.log(k);
    })
});

});
```

Comment: What are referring to as _first data_ and _second data_?

Comment: You should edit your question buddy. It is hard to understand what it is you are actually checking. Adding the code is important, but this question needs an accurate context.....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you log `k` which is a reference to inside the loop. So the loop go's key0 key1 key2 and stays key2 because thats the last value of `k`.

Use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit").on("click", function(){
        // From the button perspective this references the Native element.
        console.log(this.id);     // or $(this).attr("id")     
     })
});
```